# How To Tell if Trigger is failing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, trigger

I have a trigger, that I want to try to update a field based off the value of another table.  I have manually verified that the data exists in the other table so I know the join will work.  However, data is being inserted into the table, but no update made.  Which makes me think I did something off with the trigger

```
Create Trigger [dbo].[trig_OnInsert] ON [dbo].[SHIPMENT]
For Insert
    AS
        BEGIN
            UPDATE si
            SET si.au = au.au + ' - ' + si.au
            FROM SHIPMENT si
            JOIN alphauniversal au
            ON si.cm_controllerID = au.controllerid
            WHERE si.cm_controllerID IN (Select si.cm_controllerID FROM Inserted)
        End
```

Also, if the trigger presents an error, or doesn't execute successfully, will the record still be inserted in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear the `where` clause with the `in` is causing problems.  Try `joining` to the `inserted` table instead.  Here are two examples - one with the `in` clause and one with a `join` to the `inserted` table.  The results are different using my sample data.

```
drop table if exists shipment;
drop table if exists alphauniversal;
go
create table SHIPMENT (cm_controllerID int,au varchar(100))
create table alphauniversal (controllerid int, au varchar(100))
insert into alphauniversal values(1,'abc')
insert into alphauniversal values(2,'xyz')
go
Create Trigger [dbo].[trig_OnInsert] ON [dbo].[SHIPMENT]
For Insert
    AS
        BEGIN
            UPDATE si
            SET si.au = au.au + ' - ' + si.au
            FROM SHIPMENT si
            JOIN alphauniversal au
            ON si.cm_controllerID = au.controllerid
            WHERE si.cm_controllerID IN (Select si.cm_controllerID FROM Inserted)
            --JOIN inserted i on i.cm_controllerID=si.cm_controllerID
        End
go
insert into SHIPMENT values(1,'test1')
insert into SHIPMENT values(2,'test2')
select * from shipment
```

---

```
cm_controllerID     au
1                  abc - abc - test1
2                  xyz - test2
```

---

```
drop table if exists shipment;
drop table if exists alphauniversal;
go
create table SHIPMENT (cm_controllerID int,au varchar(100))
create table alphauniversal (controllerid int, au varchar(100))
insert into alphauniversal values(1,'abc')
insert into alphauniversal values(2,'xyz')
go
Create Trigger [dbo].[trig_OnInsert] ON [dbo].[SHIPMENT]
For Insert
    AS
        BEGIN
            UPDATE si
            SET si.au = au.au + ' - ' + si.au
            FROM SHIPMENT si
            JOIN alphauniversal au
            ON si.cm_controllerID = au.controllerid
            --WHERE si.cm_controllerID IN (Select si.cm_controllerID FROM Inserted)
            JOIN inserted i on i.cm_controllerID=si.cm_controllerID
        End
go
insert into SHIPMENT values(1,'test1')
insert into SHIPMENT values(2,'test2')
select * from shipment
```

---

```
cm_controllerID au
1               abc - test1
2               xyz - test2
```

---

The trigger code runs as part of the transaction that actually inserted the rows in the base table.  If the trigger encounters a *fatal* error, the transaction *should* roll back everything that was done during that transaction.  It's an all-or-nothing process.

You cannot swallow an exception inside a trigger even with try/catch logic.  Any exception inside a trigger WILL abort the transaction.